# How to pass existing subscription details on stripe during checkout

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I’ve different subscription plan on stripe starting from Zero. When customer sign up, I’m creating a subscription with free plan by default.

In the future, customer want to upgrade the plan through checkout session, how can I pass my existing subscription details to the checkout session to update the plan tagged to the subscription ID instead of creating multiple subscriptions.

I gone through the stripe create checkout session Doc but I couldn’t find a way to pass subscription ID in checkout session.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are trying to update an existing Subscription *through* a CheckoutSession, that is not supported.

If a customer uses Checkout to sign up for a new Price, that creates a completely new Subscription object. You cannot pass an existing Subscription ID as Checkout cannot modify that.

You should use Checkout in `mode: setup` to collect card details from your customer. This `setup` mode only collects card details but does not charge or create a Subscription on that Customer.

Then in your server-side code after you receive the `checkout.session.completed` webhook event, update the existing Subscription to switch from the "free" Price to the "paid" Price: https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update

Comment: Thank you so much @hmunoz for clarifying this. I’ve a follow up question. Will the customer card charged instantly as soon as I collect payment source and update the subscription to one of the paid plans by listening to checkout session complete webhook?

Comment: the Subscription update will result in a proration and will charge the additional amount in the next recurring cycle, but you can set `proration_behavior: always_invoice` to immediately charge for the Price switch

Comment: @hmunoz However you set the proration_behaviour, don't you need to forward the user to Checkout, in order to confirm any additional costs and the ongoing new price plan?
If so, how do you do this after modifying the subscription server side?

Comment: well that step of "forward the user to Checkout, in order to confirm any additional costs and the ongoing new price plan" has to come before you update the Subscription server-side. You ask the customer to accept the changes, then you update the Subscription server-side and show them a confirmation of the updates made.